# Reading file from SPIFFS in nodemcu using ArduinoJson

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, json

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>      
#include <FS.h>    

/* Set these to desired credentials in runtime */
struct Config {
  String ssid = "";
  String pass = "";
  bool hFlag = false;
};

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);

  //allows serving of files from SPIFFS
  Serial.println("Mounting FS...");
  if (!SPIFFS.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to mount file system");
    return;
  }

  if (readConfigFile("/LaSt.json", false)) {
    Serial.println("Config read");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to read config");
  }
}

bool readConfigFile(char* fileName, bool whichFile)
{
  File configFile = SPIFFS.open(fileName, "r");
  if (!configFile) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open config file");
    return false;
  }

  size_t size = configFile.size();
  if (size > 1024) {
    Serial.println("Config file size is too large");
    return false;
  }

  // Allocate the memory pool on the stack.
  // Use arduinojson.org/assistant to compute the capacity.
  StaticJsonBuffer<256> jsonBuffer;

  // Parse the root object
  JsonObject &root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(configFile);

  if (!root.success())
    Serial.println(F("Failed to read file, using default configuration"));

  // Copy values from the JsonObject to the Config
  Config.ssid = root["ssid"];
  Config.pass = root["pass"];
  if (whichFile)
  {
    Config.hFlag = root["hFlag"];
  }

  // We don't need the file anymore
  configFile.close();

  return true;
}
```

Compile gives error in `Copy values from the JsonObject to the Config` section. Error: `expected unqualified-id before '.' token`.

Want to read file from SPIFFS, and store in variable to use.

Comment: Config is type. you do not have an instance of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code at the top:

```
struct Config {
  String ssid = "";
  String pass = "";
  bool hFlag = false;
};
```

defines a variable "type". It's like making a new `int` or `bool`, but yours is called `struct Config`.

After making the type, you need to create declare an instance of it.

```
struct Config cfg;
```

Then, you refer to the one **you** created:

```
  // Copy values from the JsonObject to the Config struct named cfg
  cfg.ssid = root["ssid"];
  cfg.pass = root["pass"];
  if (whichFile)
  {
    cfg.hFlag = root["hFlag"];
  }
```

Note that a particular issue with ArduinoJSON and Strings is that you may get an error like:

```
error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'String' and 'ArduinoJson::JsonObjectSubscript<const char*>')
```

There is an [ArduinoJSON FAQ entry](https://arduinojson.org/v5/faq/how-to-fix-error-ambiguous-overload-for-operator/) that states

> Most of the time you can rely on implicit casts.
>
> But there is one notable exception: when you convert a JsonVariant to
>   a String.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> String ssid = network["ssid"];
> ssid = network["ssid"];
> ```
>
> The first line will compile but the second will fail with the
>   following error:
>
> ```
> error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'String' and 'ArduinoJson::JsonObjectSubscript<const char*>')
> ```
>
> The solution is to remove the ambiguity with any of the following replacement:
>
> ```
> ssid = (const char*)network["ssid"];
> ssid = network["ssid"].as<const char*>();
> ssid = network["ssid"].as<String>();
> ```

Comment: `ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'String' and 'ArduinoJson::Internals::JsonObjectSubscript<const char*>')`

Comment: [link1](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/issues/146#issuecomment-153085201), [link2](https://arduinojson.org/v5/faq/how-to-fix-error-ambiguous-overload-for-operator/)

Comment: Are you  meaning to ask a new question?

Comment: No, just mentioned that in the particular case, `string` variable type will give the error, and the workarounds are given in the links. However, those workarounds also produce warnings.

Answer (score 0):

```
      
#include FS.h
#include ESP8266WiFi.h
#include ArduinoJson.h  

/* Set these to desired credentials in runtime */

  String ssid = "tttttttt";
  String pass = "ssssssss";

#define fileName "/LaSt.json"

DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);

  //allows serving of files from SPIFFS
  Serial.println("Mounting FS...");
  if (SPIFFS.begin()) {

 if (SPIFFS.exists(fileName)) {

  File subscribedUsersFile = SPIFFS.open(fileName, "r");

  delay(10);

  String file_content = subscribedUsersFile.readString();

  JsonObject& users = jsonBuffer.parseObject(file_content);

           if(users.containsKey("ssid"))          {ssid=users["ssid"].as();}    
           if(users.containsKey("pass"))          {pass=users["pass"].as();}


    subscribedUsersFile.close();

    users.prettyPrintTo(Serial);


  }
else  {

   // Create empty file (w+ not working as expect)

   File subscribedUsersFile = SPIFFS.open(fileName, "a+");

   JsonObject& users = jsonBuffer.createObject();

   users.set("ssid", ssid);

   users.set("pass", pass);

  users.printTo(subscribedUsersFile);

  users.printTo(Serial);

  subscribedUsersFile.close();

  Serial.println("New Config File Created...\n");

  users.prettyPrintTo(Serial); 

    } 

  }
}
```

Comment: Answer could be improved by adding a sentence or two of explanation!!  Please consider.